# Declaring enum at beginning of class vs end

Tags: c++, class, enums

Take the following 2 examples below:

```
struct Coord
{
private:
    enum class Origin
    {
        Top_Left = 0,
        Center
    };
public:
    Coord(Origin origin = Origin::Top_Left) 
    {}
};


int main()
{
}
```

Running this above, I get no errors. On the other hand, when I run this, I get the following error.

```
struct Coord
{
public:
    Coord(Origin origin = Origin::Top_Left) 
    {}
private:
    enum class Origin
    {
        Top_Left = 0,
        Center
    };
};


int main()
{
}
```

> 7:16: error: expected ')' before 'origin'

In addition, in Visual Studio 2015, I get the error for identifier `Origin` not being found in the constructor.

Why is this?

Error here: <kbd>[Live Example](http://cpp.sh/3vvuo)</kbd>

Comment: @crashmstr ^ Similar

Comment: But according to ¶9.4.3 of Bjarne Stoustrup's book, PPP 4th edition: The compiler doesn't care about order of class function and data members; It takes the declarations in any order you care to present them. Does an enum class violate this?

Comment: @LogicStuff You *can* actually forward declare *strongly typed enum*s ("enum class") in C++11 and later..

Comment: So Im confused, can I do it or not? Is this a bug?

Comment: ***Is this a bug?*** It is not a bug. An enum is not a class function or data member.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah That quote is a bit oversimplified.  Within inline function `{}` braces or within member initializers, the compiler takes the whole class definition into account.  Otherwise, like in the declaration of a function, all names must be previously declared.

Comment: hmmmm.... I have to think about this, a point to ponder....

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example you are using the enumeration before it is declared.
You need to either declare it before first use (in the constructor) or add a forward declaration before first use (not going to fly here, but would in other scenarios).

The compiler needs to know what `Origin` and `Origin::Top_Left` is before its use in `Coord(Origin origin = Origin::Top_Left)`.
Remember; the compiler parses your code from the top down. It needs to know what types *are* before they are used. It *does not* view the entire compilation unit in a holistic fassion. The language just works like that - "must know what stuff is before stuff is used and I read from the top-down in every file". Sometimes "knowing stuff" needs to be the full definition, sometimes a forward declaration is enough (details of that are outside the scope of this question).

Comment: I don't think a forward declaration (`enum class Origin;`) would do. Both `Origin` and `Origin::Top_Left` need to be visible.

Comment: You may be right - sounds plausible. I admit I didn't actually check in this case.

Comment: And the problematic part is `Origin::Top_Left`.

Comment: Updated answer. Thank you for the feedback guys (gals).

Comment: Then how come when declaring integers at the bottom of a class doesn't create same error? Eg like this: `class A {public: A(int aa) : a{aa} {} //.... private: int a;};`

Comment: `int` is a built-in/known type. Not a user-defined one.